# Create Unique Keys from a large data set with multiple duplicate entries

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm interviewing for a role in a company's finance department, and as the final round of the process, I've been tasked with a case study and have 24 hours to complete it. I've been given an Excel data set of ~3700 rows.

The first task is to clean up the data for further analysis. Basically, the data is pretty bad. Like, really bad. I believe that it's a rather impossible and unfair task they're giving, but I'd like to give it a solid effort.

There is duplicate data all over the place and no Unique Keys to have a good starting point to clean the data from. There are, however, multiple instances of Employee Ids.

I thought that I could identify all the unique values of employee_id, then create a new data set based on this.

[image: It would look like this:]

As this is a Finance role, they're expecting me to complete my analysis in Excel, but I have no intention to. I'm still a Python novice, but hell if I try to clean up data in Excel and not Python.

Anyway, if you've read this far, and can offer any advice, I'd greatly appreciate it. I'm not very good yet with large data sets, but I'm learning. I have no idea if this is even the approach I should take. I just know the Excel file is super messy and going to be impossible to do any proper analysis on without cleaning it up.

If you think my proposed solution will work, how would I go about creating this? Also, I've got the data from the Excel file and the unique id's and such, that's not a problem for me.

I'd also like to save state/position for each value. So, if there is a cell with a blank, I'll need a "NaN" or whatever.

This is my novice attempt to understand data cleansing. Thanks for any help!

```
     IDS   SUP      LMO      HI
0  chris   1.0      2.0     2.0
1  chris   9.0     20.0     1.0
2  chris   3.0   2112.0    12.0
3  chris  10.0  12121.0  2112.0
4   mark   1.0      2.0     2.0
5   mark   2.0      1.0    21.0
6  susan   3.0      2.0     1.0
7  susan   1.0      2.0     2.0
8  susan   2.0      1.0     1.0
```

Comment: Not sure what you want but I think you can try `df.astype(str).groupby('IDS').agg(', '.join)` or may be `df.groupby('IDS').agg(list)`

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for. I can use GROUPBY in SQL, so I'll have to play around with this function to get it to work in Python. Thank you!

Comment: If you must do this in Excel, have a look at Power Query. Relatively easy to do a GroupBy and then concatenate the three columns.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you can set up that table you are looking for in Excel.

[image: Solution Example]

The formula in F2 is `=UNIQUE(A2:A12)`

The formula in G2 is `=TEXTJOIN(", ",FALSE,FILTER(IF(B$2:B$12="","NaN",B$2:B$12),$F2=$A$2:$A$12))`

Then copy G2 to H2 and I2.

Comment: This is really clever, thank you for this. Really appreciate it. I'll do a quick fix with this, and then import into Python for further analysis. I'll go back and figure out how to do it 100% in Python later. Big help, seriously